# Why is no downloadable PDF version available?

Tags: ep2722762a3

In reference to the patent: [EP2722762A3](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2722762A3)

Answer (score 1):

www.google.com/patents is often unreliable for viewing patents. Better is [patents.google.com](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP2722762A3/en). If you go to patents.google.com you can view the PDF file. Other sites you might try are [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/EP_2722762_A3) or [Espacenet](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?ST=singleline&locale=en_EP&submitted=true&DB=&query=EP2722762A3&Submit=Search).